# WebAssembly debug symbols (wasm:// vs file://)

Tags: webassembly, emscripten, dwarf

I need an advice on how WebAssembly binaries produced with emscripten can store their debug symbols to understand why my particular case does not work while a trivial one does.

So I was trying to test this [AV1](https://github.com/Kagami/dav1d.js) WebAssembly port but it failed with errors in malloc so I wanted to debug it. I added `-g4` and `-source-map-base` which gave me the ability to see C code, but none of the variables, all the variables in scope had the WebAssembly names - `var0` etc.

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBMHswhun-s) Youtube video, took Chrome Canary + the mentioned [Chrome DevTools WebAssembly Extension](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/12/webassembly). I made a trivial example where I compiled a single file with a trivial `main()` doing some printing. Initially it did not show variables but when I added `-gseparate-dwarf` then I got variables as well. What I saw was that the browser did a lot of `file://` based requests and Chrome asked for permissions for file access on the drive (I would assume after loading the dwarf file it got the paths, since `llvm-dwarfdump` showed full paths in the `.debug.wasm` file and the original `.wasm` file had a `external_debug_info` section pointing to the separate `.wasm` file). The biggest difference I can see is that in this case I generated a `.html` as the output from `emcc`, but as far as I can see it has similar glue code to what the library that I am trying to test already has.

Now, I tried doing the same with that project - I forked it, added a debug build with `-gseparate-dwarf` but the Chrome DevTools WebAssembly Extension now complains that it cannot load the symbols. But there is a big difference - if with the previous trivial sample the messages were always like `Trying to load simbols for <some C file path> via (<my dwarf wasm file path>)`, then now instead of the C file path it has a path like `wasm://wasm/<some hex word>` and I also see the same scheme (`wasm://`) in the source inspector. Also what seems interesting that once the `-gseparate-dwarf` is used, there is no more `sourceMappingURL` section in the `.wasm` file.

I could not find any sources of the Chrome DevTools WebAssembly Extension so I can't judge what exactly fails, but I am puzzled about the `wasm://` vs `file://` schema change between the two scenarios. Can anyone please give some guidance?

Attaching screenshots from both cases to illustrate the schema differences:
[image: Bad Example]
[image: Good Example]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems whilst trying to debug bigger project using webpack and with whole environment set with Docker.

First thing is that dwarf based debug is mutually exclusive with js source maps.
`wasm-opt` is stripping dwarf if using other flag than `-g` or `-g3` (at least it was true with emsdk 2.0.10)

Since we are building in Docker start of absolute path to sources has been different to absolute path on host PC where source lays thus wrong `file://`
to workaround this issue I have changed dwarf paths by compiler and linker option

`-ffile-prefix-map=/prefix/dir/from/docker=/absolute/path/to/src`

Then I could set break in sources found in `files://` (and see debug information like local variables in C/C++ manner).

I am using also `EM_ASM(debugger;);` to break on demand.

One thing which was not working at that time was `std:string` showing incorrectly nulled value.